# What would change if the definition of a function were the definition of a relation?

Tags: analysis, functions

So, I was confused by this since the first time I have first learned about functions: why do we require, that every element in the domain maps to one and only one element in the range. (Is that even true for a more  rigorous formulation?)

To give it more accuracy: what results would change, if we didn't require that condition and allow a function to be any kind of relation?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  The study of relations is interesting, but  what we call functions are interesting too.  Many physical situations are modeled by functions, so the concept is natural enough.

Comment: What would change is we would single out the special kind of functions that only have one output per input, give them a special name, and study them.

Comment: As an aside, it is standard to define composition for binary relations; $R S$ is the relation such that $x(RS)y$ if and only if $\exists z: xRz \wedge zSy$. If you are at all interested in category theory, note that you get a category whose objects are sets and whose morphisms are binary relations. More generally,
 you have [allegories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_(category_theory)). There are a number of theorems that boil down to saying that (except in bad settings), anything you can say in terms of functions you can say in terms of relations, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *lulu* commented, a function *is* a relation, but a stricter one.

Usually any elements can be the subject of a relation. Take the addition as an example: you can add any to numbers: $+(a,b)$, thus there can exist such a binary relation between any two numbers. However, a function marks a "relation" between two "special" (or "exact") numbers. For example $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}, \ f(x) = 2x$ cannot describe a relation between $3$ and $4$, since $f(3)=6$.

The reason why we are using functions is that they help us model certain real - life problems. Consider for example, the complexity of a program (Computer Science), which is evaluated through a function which gives us the number of steps that an algorithm requires to finish on a given data size. Namely, the quicksort algorithm maps an $n$-size array (list of elements) into $nlog_{2}{n}$ number of steps.

Comment: Yes, I have thought about the "models the real world" explanation, yet it thought there might be a more interesting/less trivial answer. However, I am happy to accept it. Thanks

Comment: @G.Chiusole You'd like more examples on there applications?

Comment: If you would like to give some, where the requirement is necessary, I'd appreciate  it

Comment: Okay then, take a simple soda machine for an example: the domain is the numbers the sodas have behind the glass and the codomain is a price, so you map the numbers to the prices. Introducing an incorrect code will give you an error, just like introducing a good code when you have not inserted the right amount of cash. The idea is to narrow down the choices the buyer can make to a number to our liking.

Answer (score 1):

I elements could map to several elements in the range, the function value wouldn't be well-defined. If both $(0, 2) \in f$ and $(0, 5) \in f$ then what would be the value of $f(0) + 3$?

However, in complex analysis one sometimes uses [multivalued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function).

Comment: How about we just give a solution set {5,8}? (Sorry for not using proper formatting btw.)

Comment: That could be useful in some cases, but one could then have a proper function $f : X \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$ so that $f(x)$ really is a set, and then define $z + f(x) = \{ z + y \mid y \in f(x) \}.$.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that does make more sense. The original point of the question (now realizing that I have not specified) was about rather pure math. I.e. Topology or differential geometry (in the pure sense) where we always talk about functions, not just relations (that should mean still using input - output (as opposed to a relation a,b -> c, like @theSongbird suggested)) again, sorry for the formatting, I am writing from my phone